# displaying a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController inside a UIPopover

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIPopover that has a navigationController stack. From the second view in that stack, I want to display an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController modally in the popover. I have this working, but when I dismiss the modalViewController, the original navigation controller for the UIPoover is missing from the popover. Is there a way to make this work properly? Code below:

```
   (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender {
       ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
          [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
        picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

       picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
       picker.modalInPopover = YES;
       [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];  
       // self is the 2nd viewController in the original navigation stack
       [picker release];
    }

    (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
       (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     }
```

Comment: I have played around with various combinations of contentSizeForViewInPopover, modalTransitionStyle, and modalPresentationStyle for several hours and had absolutely no luck in getting this to work - the picker always opens in a new view that overlays the popover. Is there some other magic you did to make it work  that's not above? If so can you add it as a comment or edit the above solution?

Comment: Well, I finally got it working. The popoverContentSize of the view that was trying to present the picker was too small. I asked the picker for its contentSizeForViewInPopover property, it said full height 320 wide, I set the popover popoverContentSize to this number, and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved as below:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```